# Get git stash --patch to ignore changes I've already added

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way to run `git stash --patch` in a way that only asks about unstaged changes?

From the docs, it looks like I should be able to do something like

```
git stash save --patch --keep-index
```

but that asks me about each change, even the ones I've already `git add`ed

In other words, if I do something like

```
echo "one" > a
echo "two" > b
git add .
git commit -m "foo"
echo "1" >> a
echo "2" >> b
git add a
```

how can I run `git stash --patch` so that I'm only asked about the change to file b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through `git stash --help`, there's simply no option to do what you want, as of version 1.7.10.

The `--keep-index` is just about keeping the index. For example, let's start from this state:

```
$ date >> file1
$ date >> file2
$ git add file1
$ git status -s
M  file1
 M file2
```

If you do `git stash --patch` now and accept all changes, you'll get:

```
$ git status -s
MM file1
```

That is, the index is preserved (when using `--patch`, the `--keep-index` is automatically on). `git stash` undid the staged changes, but you can bring them back with `git checkout file1`, thanks to having preserved the index.

Now let's return to the state before the stash:

```
$ git stash pop
$ git checkout file1
$ git status -s
M  file1
 M file2
```

And let's stash again without keeping the index:

```
$ git stash --patch --no-keep-index
$ git status -s
$
```

No changes of any kind, no staging area, the index is gone.

So no, you cannot use `git stash --patch` to stash only unstaged changes. If you don't really need the select changes interactively, then you can `git add` changes you don't want to add, and then do `git stash --keep-index` (without `--patch`):

```
$ git status -s
M  file1
 M file2
$ git stash --keep-index
$ git status -s
M  file1
```

Notice the inconsistent behavior: there are no unstaged changes to `file1` this time, unlike when we stashed with `--patch`.

Comment: Yes, that inconsistent behavior is what made me think it would work th same way with `--patch`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, `stash` is always going to inspect your index. A stash is represented internally as two commits - one that records the work dir state and the second one records the state of the index, and they are children of the HEAD.

However if what you want is to put aside your *unstaged* changes, why don't you just run `git diff > mypatchfile` and later on `git apply` your patch file.

Comment: The `git diff > patchfile` approach is possible in git, with `git stash --keep-index`, but I can't find a way to do the same with `--patch`